# JS/JQuery getting the element mouse is over

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using JQuery and I'm looking to get the element of the cursor is hovering over, however, I'm after something like this

for example:

```html
<div id="outerBox">OuterBox
    <div id="innerBox">InnerBox
    </div>
</div>
```

1. When mouse enters the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.
2. When mouse enters the “innerBox”, fire the “innerBox” event.
3. When mouse enters back to the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.

**However the only events I can find are**

`mouseover()`

1. When mouse enters the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.
2. When mouse enters the “innerBox”, fire the “innerBox” event, follow by the “outerBox” event.
3. When mouse enters back to the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.

`mouseenter()`

1. When mouse enters the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.
2. When mouse enters the “innerBox”, fire the “innerBox” event.
3. When mouse enters back to the “outerBox”, no event will fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss a little note here. Events by default during the propagation got two phases: **capturing** and **bubbling**. You can read more about them [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php).

It is something like this:

[image]

So whenever you click an item within another item, by default it will bubble trough the parent element, then the parent event will get called. To avoid such a thing you should use `.stopPropagation()`, so the actual code of yours should be something like this:

```js
document.getElementById("outerBox").addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  console.log("Mouse is over outer box");
});

document
  .getElementById("innerBox")
  .addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Mouse is over inner box");
  });
```

```html
<div id="outerBox">OuterBox
  <div id="innerBox">InnerBox
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use event propagation. When the mouse is on innerBox use the mousemove event to stopPropagation and it will not bubble to outerBox.

Refer this link https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this on jQuery.

```
      /* Mouse Enter */
      $('.outerBox').bind('mouseover',function(){
           alert("true");
      });

      /* Mouse Outer */
      $('.innerBox').bind('mouseout', function(){               
           alert("false"); 
      });
```

Comment: Negative, this won't work, I need to be adding more elements inside that element, it needs to be scalable.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the .hover API, first function triggers when you hover-in and the second when you hover-out, heres a sample:

```js
$( "#outerBox" ).hover(
  function() {
    console.log("hola")
  }, function() {
    console.log("adios")
  }
);

$( "#innerBox" ).hover(
  function() {
    console.log("innerHola")
  }, function() {
    console.log("innerAdios")
  }
);
```

```css
#outerBox {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}

#innerBox {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerBox">OuterBox
    <div id="innerBox">InnerBox
    </div>
</div>
```